# ISML isDefined() returns false altough object contains value in field

Tags: intershop

I am creating a ISML module to which I am passing a ProductBO instance. 
In the mentioned module I try to get OutgoingProductLinks field which I see it is filled with correct values which I defined in BackOffice but when isDefined() is called on that field, it returns false and when I try to use that field in `<isloop>` tag it logs error message that says:

> Loop iterator identifier '#ProductBO:ExtensibleObject:OutgoingProductLinks#' does not specify a valid Iterator.

The specific project I am working on is based on app_sf_responsive sample and therefore it uses it's ViewProduct pipeline(it is not overriden in other cartridges) which returns ProductBO object that is used in several other places and fields that are used there are normally available for use in ISML.

The following code snippet always returns false:

```
<isif condition="#isDefined(ProductBO:ExtensibleObject:OutgoingProductLinks)#" >
   <h1>Outgoing product links are defined</h1>
<iselse>
   <h1 style="color: red;">Outgoing product links are NOT defined </h1>
</isif>
```

And this is where I try to actually use mentioned field:

```
<isloop iterator="#ProductBO:ExtensibleObject:OutgoingProductLinks#" alias="ProductLink">
//Code that uses linked products
</isloop>
```

Do note that both isDefined() checks for ProductBO and ExtensibleObject are working, the problem only arises with OutgoingProductLinks

EDIT: Here is the screenshot from debugger showing product links

[Debugger showing valid product link values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vql9o.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Johannes answer. If you look at the demo shop code here is how they do it:

```
//get the productlink extension from the productBO
<isset name="ProductBOProductLinksExtension" value="#ProductBO:Extension("ProductLinks")#" scope="request">
//Link type provider : example cross/up sell, replacement 
<isset name="LinkTypeProvider" value="#ProductBOProductLinksExtension:LinkTypeProvider#" scope="request">
//get the link by id from provider See ProductLinkConstants
<isset name="LinkType" value="#LinkTypeProvider:LinkTypeByID(PageletConfigurationParameters:ProductLinkType:Name)#" scope="request">
//get a collection of linked productbos
<isset name="ProductBOs" value="#ProductBOProductLinksExtension:AccessibleOutgoingLinksLinkedObjects(LinkType)#" scope="request">
```

The advantage is that it only gets the online products.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to acquire all linked products using `ProductBO:Extension("ProductLinks")` or where to find class definition of  `ProductLinks` so I can myself inspect all available methods

Comment: For this the Javadoc is very useful. In studio go to : Help > Help Content, then Intershop Suite Cartridge API JavaDoc. Another option is to look in the gradle cache folder for the *-javadoc.jar files and extract the html from them. The class is called ProductBOProductLinksExtension.

Answer (score 3):

When I look at your object path

```
ProductBO:ExtensibleObject:OutgoingProductLinks
```

I can see you're trying to access the API of the underlying persistent object. Which is fine but make sure you're using the BOExtension named `PersistentObjectBOExtension` for that. So instead of the above use:

```
ProductBO:Extension("PersistentObjectBOExtension"):PersistentObject:OutgoingProductLinks
```

Also, there is a ISML function that checks whether or not your object path denotes an iterable object: Use `hasLoopElements(iterable)` instead of `isDefined(obj)`

Given your examples the whole thing should be written like this:

```
<isif condition="#hasLoopElements(ProductBO:Extension("PersistentObjectBOExtension"):PersistentObject:OutgoingProductLinks)#" >
   <h1>Outgoing product links are defined</h1>
<iselse>
   <h1 style="color: red;">Outgoing product links are NOT defined </h1>
</isif>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working, same problem, everything is defined up until `ProductBO:Extension("PersistentObjectBOExtension"):PersistentObject` but when I try to access `OutgoingProductLinks` it returns nothing (tried with `isDefined()`, `hasLoopElements()` and `<isloop>`)

Comment: Also I edited original question with a screenshot from IntershopStudio showing that ProductLinks exist when viewed in debugger [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vql9o.png)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also do this to retrieve the products for a specific outgoing link type:

```
<!--- Retrieve the Cross Sell products --->
<isset name="LinkedProductBOs" value="#ProductBO:SortedOutgoingProductBOLinks("ES_CrossSelling")#" scope="request"/>

<isif condition="#isDefined(LinkedProductBOs) AND hasElements(LinkedProductBOs)#">
    <isloop iterator="LinkedProductBOs" alias="LinkedProductBO">
        <isprint value="#LinkedProductBO:DisplayName#"/>
    </isloop>
</isif>
```

The `getSortedOutgoingProductBOLinks` method takes a link id as parameter. All default product links can be found in `ProductLinkConstants.java`